# Linking assets in express js depending on environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, assets, nunjucks

Is there a way of linking assets in my html files (to be precise: nunjucks files in my case) depending on the environment? I want to include several partial *.css or *.js files in the dev env in order to debug it easier and one concatanated *.min.css and *.min.js file in prod env (kind of like with assetic in Symfony).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably need to do this via a build process. Good task runners include [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/).

You could use something like [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin). This would allow you to put direct script/link tags in your html, then run a grunt command to combine them.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for :)
Btw, I'm using gulp, so that'll be [gulp-usemin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-usemin)

Comment: Perfect. Moving most of my stuff to gulp. seems like there's always a gulp package for every grunt package.

Answer (score 0):

It would vary based on your template system but the basics are like this:

In controller - make the env available to your template:

```
res.render("template", {
 env: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
});
```

Template:

```
{% if env === 'development' %}
<script>....</script>
<script>....</script>   
{% else %}
<script src="prod.min.js"></script>
{% endif %}
```

In addition use the answer by @vernak2539 to build your minify your prod.min.js file using gulp or grunt and the minify/uglify/concat plugins or do it 'manually' using things like CodeKit.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I'd been already using that method, but it always seemed to me not enough suited for that task. @vernak2539 gave right the answer that I expected :)

Comment: Great - I use both since I need all my js files separated for dev and minified for prod. I tried using the gulp onlu approach and it makes debugging harder.